# USB - RS232 communication

Tags: java, usb, serial-port, fpga, serial-communication

Is it possible to send data from a USB port to a RS232 using java code?
The RS232 is a port on FPGA board and the computer(via USB) is used to send these data.

Comment: USB is just a transport method. If there's an RS232 port at the far end of the usb connection, your underlying OS should see an RS232 port, and you just talk to it directly. The usb system will handle things for you.

Comment: In other words, use virtual COM port via USB.

Comment: It all depends on what the FPGA is programmed to do. If the FPGA is programmed to pass data between its USB port and its RS232 port, then you can do that. If not, then no.

Comment: thank you.. does java support such serial communications? i tried searching.. its seems possible only via some external api.

Comment: You'll need a USB <-> RS232 converter in the line somewhere such as an FTDI chip.  USB doesn't use RS232 natively though it is serial comms.

Answer (score 4):

You can send data to a serial port from Java using a library like [PureJavacomm](http://www.sparetimelabs.com/purejavacomm/index.html), or [RXTX](http://www.rxtx.org). The latter is a bit of the de facto standard for Java, but has some quircks, while the former is actively developed and seems to work on all current "major" platforms (personal experience).